# Which QT Version/Build is more stable?

Tags: c++, qt

I am a newbie to QT.
I used to play with QT examples on Win7 (32bit) and had a lot of fun.
Now I bought a new Win8 (64bit）PC and wanted to work with QT.

I installed that lasted vs 2012 express + Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB)
To my disappointment, After building, the exe of examples kept crashing my Win8.
I doubt that the Qt 5.1.0 is stable enough for the developing.

I only need QT as an interface.
I only use the widgets parts.
And my development time is short.

I guess maybe an older version is more stable?
Also I guess maybe the 32bit version is more stable?

1) Could anyone please suggest a more stable version and build? So that I can develop with it and release it.

2) Is it OK to run multiple versions of VS express and QT on one PC?

Comment: When my Win8 crash, windows display SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION error, then restart.

Comment: Blue screen? That is not a Qt bug, ever. It is a failure inside the OS, although possibly triggered by third-party drivers.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess maybe an older version is more stable? Also I guess maybe the 32bit version is more stable?

That's possible. If I were you that's what I would do:

1. Investigate the crash, see if that's something trivial (missing VC runtime or something like that)
2. Switch to 32bit version.
3. IF that fails, switch to older version. (4.8.3 or 4.8.1)
4. If that fails, build older version from source using older compiler (VS2008 express)
5. If that fails, thoroughly investigate cause of the crash and try to fix it.
6. If that fails, report bug to qt bug tracker and contact developers.
7. (last resort) If that fails either drop windows 8 support or switch to different gui library.

> Could anyone please suggest a more stable version and build? So that I can develop with it and release it.

4.8.1. with vs2008 express works for me, but I've never tested it on windows 8.

> Is it OK to run multiple versions of VS express and QT on one PC?

You should be able to do that (I used qt for vc and qt for mingw simultaneously), but you must make sure that "bin" folders (dlls and tools) of your qt installations are not in PATH. Otherwise things will get really messy, especially if you use several different compilers (different compilers use different name mangling schemes, so if you have qt dll for different compiler in your path, your application might not be able to start). If you're planning to use several different compilers, then you'll need one qt installation per compiler, even if qt version is identical.

Comment: I'd try 4.8.5 first, before downgrading to older minor releases.